# Make Spring application crash on OutOfMemoryError

Tags: spring, exception, project-reactor, oom

we have Spring application, deployed on Cloud Foundry. This application executes some tasks like calling different endpoints and APIs. Recently we had a problem: the application started to throw **OutOfMemoryErrors** for **Direct buffer memory** and could not proceed to execute anything. The strange thing was that the application was in state RUNNING, but did not respond to events for more than 2 hours, until restarted manually.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the application crash when this error occurs. This way, Cloud Foundry would destroy and recreate the container and the application would run again.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory; nested exception is reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory; nested exception is reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST <random-endpoint> [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerError(FluxConcatMap.java:309)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onError(FluxConcatMap.java:875)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:537)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:343)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:399)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:670)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:205)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:454)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:232)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundError(FluxReceive.java:453)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundError(ChannelOperations.java:488)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.exceptionCaught(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:144)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:728)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:826)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InternalNettyException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:701)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:676)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:215)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateNormal(PoolArena.java:197)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:139)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:129)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:396)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
    at io.netty.channel.unix.PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(PreferredDirectByteBufAllocator.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.allocate(EpollRecvByteAllocatorHandle.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:785)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$1.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:425)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:403)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We tried to use **-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError** and **-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError** options, but it turns out that they work only with heap memory.

We could try to filter the points where this error might be thrown and catch it and then kill the program. But I don't know if it is a good practice. Another problem is that this error is wrapped in another exceptions.

Could anyone explain what should be done in such situation? And how could the program become responsive again if not restarted?